# Rails understands GET request but not POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

When I access /users/registration/sign_up in my app via the browser (GET) a page renders. When I do the same thing via POST (either by submitting a form w/ the target /users/registration/sign_up or with ajax) my app returns the following error:

**Unknown action
The action 'registration' could not be found for UsersController**

I am using devise for authentication and creating a devise route for my User model using:

devise_for :users

This path should route to the devise/registrations_controller where i expect it to execute the new method (it currently does for a GET request). Maybe rails, understanding the request is a POST request automatically directs it to the create method but I don't think this is the issue because I start the debugger first thing in the create method and the debugger is not starting in my terminal before I receive this error.

Can anyone with experience with devise decipher what's going on? I'm happy to provide more info if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use `resources :users` in your routes and the URI will be `/users/new`?

Answer (score 4):

Devise adds routes to your Rails app, which you can see by running `rake routes` from a terminal:

```
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)
                       PUT    /users/password(.:format)
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)
                       PUT    /users(.:format)
                       DELETE /users(.:format)
                  root        /(.:format)
```

And as you discovered, there is a `GET /users/sign_up` but no `POST /users/sign_up`. When creating Devise expects `POST /users`, for which you can use the helper method `user_registration_path`. This gets handled by `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you! Is there any way to add a specific route? Say I don't currently have it but would like to add: POST /users/registration? Also, what does the .:format mean?

Comment: `post 'users/registration'` routes to UsersController#registration. The `.format` refers to the format requested (HTTP, XML, JSON, etc). All of this is described in the Rails Routing Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html